# Cannot get git to ignore files and folders

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder that I wanna keep track of using git but I don't wanna add certain files and folders. To do that I am trying to use `.gitignore` file but it doesn't seem to be working, because when I enter `git status` again it shows me those files and folder that I wanna ignore.

[image]

This is my working project directory. At this point I started empty git. Then I created a `.gitignore` file with the following content.

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

.env
/node_modules/
model.txt
```

I even add and commited the `.gitignore` file. Now when I enter `git status` I get this.

```
D:\Shashank.summer\test_API>git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .env
        app.js
        config/
        extra.md
        model.txt
        models/
        node_modules/
        package-lock.json
        package.json
        routes/
        try.js

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What do here ?

Comment: This might seem redundant, but can you also show the output of this command in the question? `cat .gitconfig`

Comment: It looks like they might have been staged before youy added the .gitignore. Try `git restore --staged <paths...>` to unstage the unwanted files. If they are still bein gstaged there is someting else going on

Comment: @joshmeranda `git status` lists the files untracked, not added or modified.

Comment: `cat .gitconfig` - output : no such file or directory; But the config file contains this : [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true

Comment: Found the issue : I am stupid - Thank you for diving in. I was commiting the `.gitignore` file but was not saving the file before the commit so it was taking its initial version i.e. EMPTY

Answer (score 0):

I see you have solved your problem. Just a little extra knowledge, say for example you want all your `.exe` or `.js` or any file of any format to be exclude, then just open your `.gitignore` file and type `*` and then your file format.

say for example you want to exlude all the files of format `.exe` then all  you need to type is `*.exe`.